# Phalcon URL assembly - how to supply parameters

Tags: php, phalcon

I have the following Phalcon route:

```
$router->add('/:controller/:action/:params', [
    'module' => 'secured',
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 2,
    'params' => 3,
    'namespace' => 'My\Namespace\Controllers'
])->setName('main');
```

I am trying to assemble URL for that route, which should look like this:

**/user/register/admin/john**

Where, "user" is controller name, "register" is action and there are two params: [0] = 'admin', [1] = 'john'.

I am assembling it as follows:

```
$url = $this->di['url']->get([
    'for' => 'main',
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action' => 'regiser',
    'params' => [
        'admin',
        'john'
     ]
]);
```

However, parameters are not in the $url:

**/user/register**

How can I make :params go into final URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot check this right now, but does:

```
array(
    'for' => 'main',
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action' => 'regiser',
    'admin'
    'john'
);
```

works as you wish?

Answer (score 1):

I found the only way how to do this. Do it myself:

```
$this->url->get(array(
        'for' => 'main',
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action' => 'register',
        'params' => implode("/", array('admin', 'john'))
));
```